# Querying Multiple Site Collection using Client Object Model without ClientAccessPolicy.xml

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint, sharepoint-clientobject

Am working on a Silverlight integration with SharePoint. I use the Client Object Model to fetch information from list of multiple site collections. To do this successfully, I currently use the ClientAccessPolicy.xml for the Client Object Model to fetch data from multiple Site Collections. Now the problem that I have is, my client does not allow the file ClientAccessPolicy.xml to be put on the Virtual Directory. Is there a workaround to this? Is there a way to fetch the lists from Site Collections without ClientAccessPolicy.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I`m fairly sure the only way to bypass the lack of a clientaccesspolicy.xml when using Silverlight is to create your own server-side web service proxy that wraps the SharePoint API/Services calls and exposes whatever you want to send to Silverlight from that web-service, keeping it in the same domain as the Silverlight app.

Comment: i agree. i'd only create a wrapper if there is a real need tho, otherwise i'd use the default SP web services